# Range query: Find amount of numbers in a range distinct from the `gcd` of the numbers in the range

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm doing a competitive programming problem, and I've been trying to solve it for a couple of days, but my solution is not efficient. I'd like to get some help in it.

We're given an array `data[n]` of `n` positive integers. We're going to perform `q` queries on it.

A query `a, b` consists of finding the amount of numbers in the subarray `data[a, b]` (both endpoints inclusive) distinct from the `gcd` of the entire subarray.

What I did first, was to implement `gcd` via Euclid's algorithm, then for each query, I iterated through `data[a, b]` and found it's `gcd` (first I took the `gcd` of the first 2 elements, and I kept tooking a `gcd` between the next element of the array and my `gcd` so far). Then I compared each element of the subarray with this value and counted up.

This is clearly not the best way to solve this problem, so I tried speeding it up via a sparse table.

Since `gcd` is associative and idempotent, I can use O(n lg n) space and O(1) time to find the `gcd` of a range. The table is built getting the answer for all queries with interval length a power of 2, and then combining intervals to get the answer for an arbitrary query.

The issue I now present is that I still iterate through the range and check how many elements are different from the `gcd` I computed using the sparse table.

I was wondering if there was a better way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your table the count of numbers in the range, and the count of numbers which are different from the GCD.

As you merge to find the GCD, you keep track of both numbers.  If the new GCD is the same, you just pull them up from the child node.  If the new GCD is different than the child node, ALL of the numbers below the child node are different from the GCD.

To answer any particular query will now require at most `O(log(n))` time.